# How to stop inner onClick event's propogating into outer onSubmit event in React?

Tags: reactjs, event-handling

I have an React application where I retrieve data from an Unsplash api. I implemented a form with several input fields and buttons in order to request data from this api.

Besided my input field I have created a button and passed a function `clearInputField` on `onClick` event, it clears the input field's value with a single click. However, after this implementation, the event started bubling and triggering `onSubmit` event which I have on my form. To prevent this behaviour, I passed `e.preventDefault()`  in my `clearInputField`  function.

Now everything works fine, except that I can't use ENTER key, if I want to trigger the form submit. Instead, the ENTER key now triggers `clearInputField`  function.

How in the given situation I could preserve the functionality of `clearInputField` function and at the same time have ENTER key triggering `onSubmit` event?

```
export const SearchImages = (props) => {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [imagesTotal, setImagesTotal] = useState(0);
  const [inputError, setInputError] = useState(false);
  const [noResultsError, setNoResultsError] = useState(false);
  const [excessInputError, setExcessInputError] = useState(false);
  const [topLoader, setTopLoader] = useState(false);
  const [bottomLoader, setBottomLoader] = useState(false);
  const focusOnSearch = useRef(null);


  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    if (query.length === 0) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setInputError(true);
    } else if (query.length > 50) {
      e.preventDefault();
      setInputError(false);
      setExcessInputError(true);
    } else {
      setInputError(false);
      setExcessInputError(false);
      setTopLoader(true);
      searchPhotos(e);
      props.addSavedQuery(query);
    }
  };


  const searchPhotos = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setNoResultsError(false);
    UnsplashAccessKey.search
      .photos(query, 1, 10)
      .then(toJson)
      .then((json) => {
        setTopLoader(false);
        setImagesTotal(json.total);
        if (json.results <= 0) {
          setNoResultsError(true);
        } else {
          setImages(json.results);
        }
      });
  };

  const clearInputField = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setQuery("");
    stopPropagation(e);
  };

  return (
      <form className="search-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className="search-form__input--wrapper">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="query"
            placeholder='Use keywords, ex: "phone"'
            value={query}
            onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
            ref={focusOnSearch}
            className="search-form__input"
          />
          <button className="search-form__btn--clear" onClick={clearInputField}>
            &#88;
          </button>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" className="search-form__btn--submit">
          Search
        </button>
        <span
          className="search-form__warning"
          style={
            inputError || excessInputError
              ? { display: "block" }
              : { display: "none" }
          }>
          {inputError
            ? "The search field should not stay empty!"
            : "" || excessInputError
            ? "50 characters max length exceeded. Use concise keywords. This is not a poetry app!"
            : ""}
        </span>
      </form>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `type="button"`

```
<button className="search-form__btn--clear" type="button" onClick={clearInputField}>
  &#88;
</button>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. But if I for example, change it to type="search",  this comes with a default  implementation of the x button that clears input field and the form submit can be triggered. Unfortunately, it's not browser compatible. So, I would be rather having my own, custom implementation

Comment: I say about the type of button and you seem to talk about the type for input.

Answer (score 0):

use `stopPropagation` method of the event.

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Sorry, but it does not work on React's syntetic events.

Comment: you mean, e.stopPropagation inside clearInputField doesn't work?

Comment: Exactly, the behaviour remains the same if I use it or not.